# Array from Object is empty. Javascript and React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-router, redux-saga

I am writing some *react* frontend application. I want to pass just `header` from `table` *object* to my function. I am using *react-redux* and *redux-saga*

In the `reducer.js` I am creating this object `table`, it has 2 arrays inside.

Code starts in `render()` and then calls `Table` which calls `TableRows` and `TableHead`

Later I pass table to `TableHead` as `data` variable (to avoid using as *html* *table*). But when I do `data.header` or `data["header"]`  in `TableHead` method, the array I receive has 0 length and it is empty.

**How can I get this array? I have to use map or some built-in functionality?**

```
// Picture is created from this snippet
//AuthorsTable.js
const TableHead = ({data}) => {
  console.log("Making header")
  // var header = data.header
  console.log(data)
  console.log(data["header"])
  console.log(data.header)
```

[image: Firefox console]

```
//reducer.js
...
    case 'UPDATE_TABLE':        
        // console.log("Updating", action.author_obj.id)
        var proto_obj = action.value;
        // console.log("value:", obj)

        var words = Object.keys(proto_obj).map(function (key) {
            return {id: key, label: proto_obj[key]}; 
        });


        newState.table.header = [...newState.table.header, action.author_obj]
        newState.table.content = [...newState.table.content, [words]]

        return newState
...
```

```
//AuthorsTable.js

const TableHead = ({data}) => {
  console.log("Making header")
  // var header = data.header
  console.log(data)
  console.log(data["header"])
  console.log(data.header)


  var header = Object.keys(data.header).map(function (key) {
            return {id: key, label: data[key]}; 
        });
  console.log(header)

const TableRows = ({data}) => {
    return (<tbody><tr><td>content</td></tr></tbody>)
    // for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    //   let children = []
    //   //Inner loop to create children
    //   for (let j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
    //     children.push(<td>{`Column ${j + 1}`}</td>)
    //   }
    // return children
  // }
}

const Table = ({data}) => {return(
  <table>
      <TableHead data={data} />    
      <TableRows data={data} />    
  </table>
)}

class AuthorsTable extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

  }

  render() {
    const state = this.state;
    // console.log(this.props.table)
    return (    
        <Table data={this.props.table} />

      // "Hello"
    )
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
  // authors: state.authors,
  selectedItems: state.selectedItems,
  table: state.table,
  };
};

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
)(AuthorsTable);
```

Comment: Create code-sandbox for it

Answer (score 0):

This was not working.

<s>`newState.table.header = [...newState.table.header, action.author_obj]`</s>

<s>`newState.table.content = [...newState.table.content, [words]]`</s>

**Solution:**
Creating new object, and then replacing it in state.

```
    ...
    // reducer.js
    // working code
    const newState = { ... state };
    var new_table = {
    header: [...newState.table.header, action.author_obj],
    content: [...newState.table.content, [words]],
    }
    newState.table = new_table

    return newState
```

> somebody knowing JS better can explain this further